# It's possible to create an inter-species university?

Tags: creature-design

Imagine if we could ignore the biology boundaries, for example, allowing aquatic monsters like mermaids to stay hydrate while being on land, then it's possible to create a study place where all type of fictional species (including humanoid races like elf, etc) could attend the same lecture like everyone? Of course, there is an obvious boundary between their physical traits, but I don't think there isn't a solution for this.

Okay, imagine there is a big lecture hall. At the front, there are chairs for small species like halfling, then behind them are chairs for species that has the same size of human, like Lampad, etc. Further behind, there are places without any chairs for the oversize species, like centaur, etc, with adjustable desk that its height could be changed taller or shorter. Some species that couldn't move on land, like mermaids and their entire subspecies, may need some special support like electric wheelchair to move around. Also, for creatures sleeping during the days or sensitive with sunlight like vampire, zombies, etc, they could join the night courses to avoid the situation of their smelly rotten bodies distracting everyone or the vampire would attacking other living beings. We could also make class that separate the predator species with other, or the outdoor class for plant types one, since for some of them, their roots needed to attach to the ground. The same things could apply with their dorm rooms, divining each individuals according to their sizes, lifestyles, etc, so they won't kill or bothering each others, especially due to their environment adaptation issues.

That's my opinion, There are many holes in this idea, but I'm just wondering if it's possible or not. Let me know what you guys think (also, sorry for my broken English).

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What is the purpose of this forced cohabitation of sophonts which were never meant to live together? What does this unnatural lecture hall do which cannot be done using separate lecture halls adapted to the specifics of each kind of student? (And the question seems to imply that the main activity at university is listening to lectures. That's false. The main activity is working together in seminar rooms and laboratories. Students often skip the lectures completely as a waste of time -- lectures convey information at the speed of speech, and a university student can read many times faster.)

Comment: In an imaginary world all things are possible, it's just a matter of rationalizing them for the purpose of a story or other application. For future reference, please be aware that we do not have a formal policy for "review my idea" questions as they do not naturally fit within Stack Exchange's rules where questions must anticipate a best answer even if not selected. Per the [tour], SE is not a discussion forum. Thus, I must second @TheDemonLord's comment... what's your question? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but as with all "political" systems, it would be very expensive - so most likely a single, unique building, most likely in some parliamentary political location. Why is it expensive?
Because it has to be equal environment access for all. Think like wheel-chair accessible, on steroids. Basically everyone within the institute, will have a personalized spacesuit/forcefield to keep the environment they are used too.

Deep-Sea creatures and gas-planet creatures might be used to extreme pressures, other species may carry bacteria that is highly dangerous for other creatures. Creatures may need some forms of radiation or heavy gravity, other creatures would find lethal.

So, its a ridiculous expensive, photo op stunt. Everyone else works with robot proxies or go to the university on there home planet.
So all it takes is one bad turn for the overall political system, for this place to become dangerous. High energy force-fields, lethal dangerous environments and all it takes is one unpaid janitor and students kill one another by accident.

Comment: +1 for addressing the basic complexity of the issue, but also for pointing out that we solve this on a much more limited basis already. Modern universities accommodate differences in culture, language, disability, even economic limitations. The OP's effort truly is all of this on steroids, but if it can be done in a small way, it can be done in a big way... but that opens the doors to all kinds of problems that would be interesting in a story.